# GNU Makefile running on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, gnu-make

I've written a simple generic makefile for c++. It works great on Debian/Ubuntu.
I would like to know if it could be running on MAC OS. I ask the question because i have no Mac OS at home and i can't test. Furthermore, if you have some advice, let's go.
I'm not sure about these lines
CXXFLAGS += -D OSX
LDFLAGS  := -stdlib=libstdc++
I precise that it for build only STL C++ programm for the moment. No dynamic libraries.

```
# sources (*.cpp)
SRC  := sources
# headers (*.cpp)
INC  := include
MAIN := kwic_personnel.cpp
EXEC := prog

# main file is in current directory or in sources file
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(MAIN))","")
    sources := $(MAIN) $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
else
    sources := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
endif
# obj files
objects := $(sources:.cpp=.o)
# dep files
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -I $(INC) -MMD -MP -g -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -Weffc++ -Werror

# OS name
UNAME := $(shell uname -s)

# if linux
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    # my own choices on compilator with Debian
    LDFLAGS  := -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    LDLIBS   := -lcurl
# else but mac OS
else
    # NOT SURE ABOUT THAT
    CXXFLAGS += -D OSX
    LDFLAGS  := -stdlib=libstdc++
endif

# linking
$(EXEC) : $(objects)
    @echo "Generation du fichier executable..."
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
    $(RM) $(objects) $(deps)
    @echo "Compilation réussie !"

# compilation of cpp files
$(SRC)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

# remove exec
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(EXEC)

# dependencies
-include $(deps)
```

Comment: At first blush it's a definite maybe. If you want better cross-platform building, use a higher level build system like cmake or meson.

Comment: I use GNU Makefile on Linux (using `gcc`), macOS (using `gcc` and `clang`), and Windows (via Cygwin; using `CL.EXE` and `gcc`).  So, **yes**, it is possible, but handling the cross-platform issues is on your shoulders.

Comment: It's just for basic c++ exercices programs given at college. No big projects and by the way we have to use only Debian or Ubuntu. I'm just curious for MAC OS. So i tried to make a compatible makefile but i can't test it. It's frustrating haha. I also tried to implement a PHONY run but i have always a "permission denied" even with sudo.

Comment: As far as GNU make is concerned you can definitely run it on mac OS. But as the default version delivered by Apple is quite old (3.81, about 15 years old), if you use recent GNU make features, you'll probably need to tell your end users that they will need to install a  more recent version of GNU make. The Homebrew and MacPorts projects both provide GNU make 4.3 and are very easy to use.

Comment: Same for the other tools you are using: if the mac OS versions are not what you need, Homebrew and MacPorts are probably the solution. I work everyday on Debian Stretch and mac OS Mojave, I use advanced features of GNU make V4.3 and, thanks to MacPorts everything works as I expect. From time to time I must `#ifdef _DARWIN_` but it is quite rare.

Answer (score 1):

I use gnu make on both Mac and Ubuntu. I do a bunch of things I'll explain.

First my Ubuntu is via a local Docker container, and it NFS mounts my local Mac work directory. So I can edit locally on my Mac but compile for Linux. This means if I build on both, I could have a mix of different targets being built. Clearly, this is problematic, so here are some tricks.

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)
MACAPPEND=
LIB_ARGS= -cvrU
ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    MACAPPEND=-mac
    CXX=clang++
    LIB_ARGS= -cvr
endif
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := obj${MACAPPEND}
DEPDIR := .d
BINDIR := bin${MACAPPEND}
```

Then it's the same ${SRCDIR} for everything, but $OBJDIR} might resolve to obj or obj-mac. Same with bin and bin-mac. I compile with this:

```
${OBJDIR}/%.o : %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cc) ${CXXFLAGS} $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Note that I do this stuff so much, that I produce a Makefile-Base and stuff it into /usr/local/etc and then can do this:

```
include /usr/local/etc/Makefile-Base
```

If I'm making a library:

```
LIBNAME=show${MACAPPEND}
LIB=lib/libshow${MACAPPEND}.a
lib: ${LIB}

${LIB}: ${LIB_OBJ}
    @mkdir -p lib
    ar ${LIB_ARGS} ${LIB} ${LIB_OBJ}
    ranlib ${LIB}
```

See LIB_ARGS used here and defined near the top of this post.

Note that a LOT of what I'm doing is because of the way I share my directory across both environments and might be bulding in both. There are very few things that you need to do special on Mac.

Comment: so my makefile now has no chance to work on MAC ? Thx for your response Joseth. If not, i'll give up i think.

Comment: I didn't say that. Chances are very high it will work just fine. As I stated, I do the extra stuff because of how I work. The only thing that's really different are the args to the "ar" command. But you can steal from the stuff I cut & pasted, because sometimes library names are different (some of the boost libraries for instance). If you treat Mac and Linux exactly the same to start, you're probably not bad. You can see how I'm testing for the environment. Check for UNAME == Darwin.